# Ran verses run in a sentence usage

Tags: tense, verbs

I’m curious which sentence is correct and why.

> I let it ran.
>
> I let it run.

The context of the conversation is in reference to an event that occurred in the **past**.

Answer (score 4):

> I let it run

is the only grammatical construction.

*Let* in the permissive sense takes an *unmarked infinitival* clause: that is, a clause whose main verb is cast as a bare infinitive, without a *to* marker.

You are perhaps confused by the fact that *let* is an irregular verb: its present (except 3sg) and infinitive form is identical with its past form and its past participle.

> I usually let the machine run at full speed.
>   I let the machine run at full speed yesterday.
>   I have often let the machine run at full speed.